# Using/Compiling C++ with Cython

Tags: python, c++, c, gcc, cython

I am working on a project which required a large number of dictionary lookups in cython. To try improve the speed I attempted to replace the dictionaries with unordered_maps from libcpp.

```
#!python
#cython: boundscheck=False, wraparound=False, infer_types=True,cdivision = True
from libcpp.unordered_map cimport unordered_map
```

However when I attempt to compile with gcc on the command line the compilation fails with

```
CAStar2.c:482:19: fatal error: utility: No such file or directory
 #include <utility>
                   ^
compilation terminated.
```

It seems the compiler cannot find multiple required files.
How would I point it to those files?

Comment: Where do you get the "CAStar2.c"? If you compile with gcc default options, it will treat it as "c" file by using its extension but `utility` header is part of C++ standard library.

Comment: CAStar.2 is the program I am attempting to compile. It is a C file generated by `cython -a CAStar2.pyx`. Cython supportes C++ however I cannot work out how to create it from a .pyx file.  Trying to compile it with language = "c++" fails with thousands of errors

Comment: A quick approach (not guaranteed to work and may introduce potential bugs, be aware) is to change the extension from ".c" to ".cpp" or use gcc option "-x c++".

Comment: It's so weird that Cython should be able to work seamlessly with C++. Can you share a few errors when you compile with `language=c++`?

Comment: Take a look at http://cython.readthedocs.io/en/latest/src/userguide/wrapping_CPlusPlus.html especially the setup.py

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I turns out the issue was my compiler not activating support for c++11 which cython seems to produce. Adding the option `-std=c++11` everything compiled normally.
Thanks though to everyone who helped.

Answer (score 0):

The cython generated C file needs to be compiled by a setuptools `Extension`.

If compiling manually all the include and lib directories that setuptools would otherwise use need to be also specified manually.

See [cython setuptools documentation here](http://cython.readthedocs.io/en/latest/src/userguide/wrapping_CPlusPlus.html#specify-c-language-in-setup-py) and [here for a minimal compile from cmd line example](http://cython.readthedocs.io/en/latest/src/reference/compilation.html?highlight=gcc#compiling-from-the-command-line).